# How Can I Add a Prefetch to a NamedQuery/MappedSelect?

Tags: apache-cayenne

I have a named query in my model that's set to fetch Data Objects.

```java
<query name="artists" type="SQLTemplate" root="obj-entity" root-name="Artist">
    <property name="cayenne.GenericSelectQuery.fetchingDataRows" value="false"/>
    <sql><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Artist]]></sql>
</query>
```

My actual query is more complicated and can't be done using ObjectSelect.

I'd like to add a prefetch, but I haven't come up with a solution I like. Here's what I've tried:

1. Faulting

   ```java
   List<Artist> artists = MappedSelect.query(...).select(context);
   artists.forEach( artist -> artist.getPaintings.size() );
   ```

   This doesn't refresh from the database and requires a separate query for each artist.
2. Call `RelationshipQuery` directly

   ```java
   List<Artist> artists = MappedSelect.query(...).select(context);
   for (Artist artist : artists) {
       Query query = new RelationshipQuery(artist.getObjectId(), Artist.PAINTINGS.getName());
       ((ToManyList) artist.getPaintings()).setObjectList(context.performQuery(query));
   }
   ```

   I don't think this does everything it's supposed to and it still requires a separate query for each artist.
3. Subclass `MappedSelect` to expose `getReplacementQuery`

   ```java
   class MySelect<T> extends MappedSelect<T> {
       ...
       public SQLTemplate getReplacementQuery(...) {
           return (SQLTemplate) super.getReplacementQuery(...);
       }
   }
   MySelect query = new MySelect(...);
   SQLTemplate template = query.getReplacementQuery(context.getEntityResolver());
   template.addPrefetch(Artist.PAINTINGS.disjointById());
   template.setCacheStrategy(QueryCacheStrategy.NO_CACHE);
   List<Artist> artists = query.select(context);
   ```

   I don't like having to access private API. I also think this solution might fail if I set any params after accessing the replacement query.
4. Change package to access `BaseMetadata`

   ```java
   package org.apache.cayenne.query;
   ...
   MappedSelect<Artist> query = MappedSelect.query(...);
   BaseQueryMetadata metaData = (BaseQueryMetadata) query.getMetaData();
   metaData.mergePrefetch(Artist.PAINTINGS.disjointById());
   metaData.setCacheStrategy(QueryCacheStrategy.NO_CACHE);
   Artist artist = query.select(context);
   ```

   This seems slightly better, but I'm still accessing private API and it requires writing code in a different package (or using reflection). It also still has a forced downcast.
5. Refetch objects

   ```java
   List<Artist> artists = MappedSelect.query(...).select(context);
   ObjectSelect.query(Artist.class)
       .where(ExpressionFactory.matchAnyExp(artists))
       .prefetch(Artist.PAINTINGS.disjoint())
       .cacheStrategy(QueryCacheStrategy.NO_CACHE);
       .select(context);
   ```

   This is what I'm trying to avoid, since I'm refetching rows I just retrieved.

Is there a preferred way to add a prefetch to a named query, like a property I can set in the model? Or is there a good way to refresh a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `MappedSelect` nor `SQLSelect` support prefetches, which is an unfortunate omission (I'll follow up to fill this gap in Cayenne). You may have to switch to the older, less pretty, but totally functional `SQLTemplate` query that does:

```
SQLTemplate q = new SQLTemplate(MyEntity.class, "SELECT * FROM...");
q.addPrefetch(MyEntity.SOME_RELATIONSHIP.getName());
```

Comment: I look forward to the API changes. In the mean time it's important for me to keep the SQL in the model so I found this solution: `SQLTemplate q = ((SQLTemplateDescriptor) context.getEntityResolver().getQueryDescriptor(...)).buildQuery();`